# move folder from one location to another based on list in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have code that copy files but i am not able to move whole folder.

I have this code:

```vb
Sub copyfiles()
'Updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim xSFileDlg As FileDialog, xDFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xSPathStr As Variant, xDPathStr As Variant
    Dim xVal As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", "KuTools For Excel", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xSFileDlg.Title = "Please select the original folder:"
    If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xDFileDlg.Title = "Please select the destination folder:"
    If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xVal = xCell.Value
        If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
            FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're having a problem it's useful to describe exactly what happens when you run your code.   Start by commenting out the `On Error Resume Next`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the base code for what you want to do. Here I have only taken one address from excel sheet. You can loop through the list of addresses in Excel and it will move the folder to your desired location.

```
MoveFolder macro
 Dim FSO As Object
 Dim oldPath As String, newPath As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

oldPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder1"
newPath = Range("A1")

FSO.MoveFolder oldPath, newPath

End Sub
```